# How to create a table using values of another table without causing SQL injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

[image]I have a table in the database with columns `Profile_Name` and `Profile_Tip`.

I have a textbox in my application where I enter the text for the table name. I want to create a table in the database with this name. I want to use `Profile_Name` values as the column names of the newly created table without causing SQL injection. Kindly help. I am a fresher using the languages. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind or requirement would lead you to create sql structure based on user input? There may better solution

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server Management Studio..

Comment: Who gets to choose what 'schema'/'library' things go into - can you control access with that?  Give them (mostly) complete control over their schema, and their schema only (no access elsewhere, except some common ones)?  Alternatively, can you force table names to be only a single word (Barring `_`)?  That would eliminate pretty much all attempts to inject based on that field.  And if everything is in the same schema (multiple users with same access), what happens if two people choose the same table name?

Comment: It is a huge red flag that you want users to create tables.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to fetch the data you need to use from `Profile_Name` and `Profile_Tip` and use them in a [parameterized query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) - this should resolve most possible cases of SQL Injection.

However, the database/solution you describe (creating tables based on user input) sounds like a bad design. Difficult to say without knowing more about the requirements, but think about a way to achieve them without generating tables based on user input.

Comment: Is it possible to use parameters in query to substitute object names rather than data?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek - Sure, though you would have to resort to [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use SqlParameter!
For example,

```
SqlConnection connection;
        // initializes connection to your DB
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = @"ALTER TABLE @TABLE_NAME ADD @COLUMN_NAME varchar(50)";
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TABLE_NAME", tableName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COLUMN_NAME", columnName);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Hope you got the idea.

Comment: So should I first retrieve Profile_Name(as mentioned in my question) in a ListBox. and the use you code? Like: command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TABLE_NAME", TextBox1.Text); command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COLUMN_NAME", ListBoxBox1.Items);  ????????

Comment: In your case, first you must validate TextBox1.Text to insure that text doesn't contains any sql

Comment: By you sentence I assume that you are asking if I am using any SQL names to fill the text box. In which case in my the textbox, it is the user entered texts.

Comment: Also I want to CREATE TABLE not ALTER TABLE

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamicaly

You can use execute with `EXEC  sp_executesql`

Sample :

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(100) 
SELECT @string = ".."
EXEC sp_executesql @string
```

Comment: I dint get you exactly.. Kindly provide little more information by using the data names I have specified. So that I can know exactly where to use and what I am doing. thank you.